# Java 64bit install doesn't work; only 32bit does?

Tags: java

This isn't coding related, I hope that's fine. I've been trying to run a modpack through techniclauncher, but I can't get the launcher to even open.

If I have java 64bit installed, anything I open that uses java just stays in the taskbar/task manager for about 3 seconds, then closes with no error message. 32 bit java works, but I need 64bit so I can dedicate more than 1GB of ram to a modpack.

I am on Windows 10 x64 build 1903, my java version is JRE 8u231 but no matter which version of java I install the problem persists.
Things I've tried:

uninstalling/reinstalling

Using revouninstaller from Britec's tutorial

Installing an old version of java (Java 6 had the same problem, same with older versions of java 8)

jarfix

updating graphics drivers (gtx 1070 currently on 441.41)

I have no idea what caused it; it worked fine a few months ago and when I tried to launch a modpack yesterday the launcher wouldn't start. Even the java control panel doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

[EDIT: screenshots of event viewer]

https://gyazo.com/70c9b5599fe3331e927171a6ac279e25

https://gyazo.com/1786c8011182933e3671481966394507

https://gyazo.com/da029d89cfdf0da6a3af4cb5a4c9b083

https://gyazo.com/a0a377129d51ee7b51a4b2aefce8723f

https://gyazo.com/4ad84929c5f1c0e93834289616f4afb2

This all happened at about the same time when I tried to open the Java control panel

Comment: And you're sure you download the x64 windows installer from here? https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Can you tell us what's happening in the windows event viewer? 
(Windows Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application)?

Comment: I downloaded the x64 installer of JDK from there, but it's JRE that doesn't work (I did reinstall jdk also but that didn't fix it)

@MattV As for the event viewer, I don't really know how to use it but there definitely is something happening. I'm going to edit screenshot links into the original post if that helps.

Comment: You installed two things? JDK includes JRE

Comment: 32bit Java should let you assign up to 4GB RAM, though. I'm not aware of this 1GB limit

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to indicate the crash has something to do with graphics / Direct3D.  Finding the root cause might be difficult, but one thing to try would be updating your graphics drivers.

Another thing to try would be to disable Java's graphics hardware acceleration.  The [System Properties for Java 2D Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html) page has instructions on how to do this.  Under Windows, to configure globally for all launched Java applications, set the environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` to disable Direct3D acceleration.

Comment: Could be related to [JDK-8179382](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179382), either way `-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false` should help.